# Nodejs check to see if client is still connected

Tags: node.js, socket.io, connection, client

I am using v0.10.37.  My logic is all set up by my detection code is not correct.

if (typeof(socket.to(key).connected[key]) ==='undefined')

is what I'm currently using to detect, I also tried typeof(socket.to(key).connected[key].connected which threw an undefined error (reason why I changed the code to the above). I need the code to work so the clients array when adding a new clientid to a client it removes all invalid clientids so notifications can be pushed smoothly to the client.

```
var http = require('http');
var io = require('socket.io');
server = http.createServer(function(req, res){});
server.listen(8082);
var socket = io.listen(server);
var clients = {};
socket.on('connection', function(client)
{
    client.on('setUserId',function(userid)
    {
        console.log("add");
        if(typeof(clients[userid[0]])==='undefined') 
        clients[userid[0]] = {};
        clients[userid[0]][userid[1]] = userid[1];
        console.log(clients);   
        for(var key in clients[userid[0]]) 
        {
            if (typeof(socket.to(key).connected[key]) ==='undefined') 
            delete clients[userid[0]][userid[1]];
        }   
    });
    client.on('removeUserId',function(userid)
    {
        console.log("remove");
        delete clients[userid[0]][userid[1]];
        counter = 0;
        for(var key in clients[userid[0]]) 
        counter++;
        if (counter == 0)
        delete clients[userid[0]];  
        console.log(clients);
    }); 
    client.on('message', function(msg)
    {
        if (msg.indexOf("notifications") != -1)
        {
            userid = msg.replace("notifications","");
            for(var key in clients[userid]) 
            {
                sessionid = key;
                console.log("notification sent" + msg);
                socket.to(sessionid).emit('message',msg);
            }           
        }
        else if (msg.indexOf("message") != -1)
        {
            userid = msg.replace("message","");
            for(var key in clients[userid]) 
            {
                sessionid = key;
                console.log("private message sent" + msg);
                socket.to(sessionid).emit('message',msg);
            }
        }       
        else
        {
            ids = msg.split(",");
            for (i = 0; i < ids.length;i++)
            {
                userid = ids[i];
                for(var key in clients[userid]) 
                {
                    sessionid = key;
                    displaymessage = "notifications" + msg;
                    console.log("notification sent" + displaymessage);
                    socket.to(sessionid).emit('message',displaymessage);
                }
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself, the issue was deleting the wrong index.

delete clients[userid[0]][key]

did the trick.